# Compute the spectrum of a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

For operator $T:C([0,1])\rightarrow C([0,1])$, $$T(f)(x)=\int_0^x\dfrac{f(t)}{\sqrt{x-t}}dt$$ Now, I want to find $\sigma(T)$, which is spectrum of $T$.

I proved $T$ is a compact operator, so $0\in\sigma(T)$, but how can I proceed?

Many thanks

Comment: A compact operator may not have $0$ in its spectrum. Consider for instance the identity operator on a finite-dimensional space.

Comment: @QuantumSpace but every compact operator over an infinite dimensional space has $0$ in its spectrum (actually $0$ lies in the spectrum of a compact operator iff the space is infinite dimensional), just thought we should add this:)

Comment: Yes, you are right and that's clearly satisfied here. The quick reason is of course that $0$ is not in the spectrum of a compact operator iff this compact operator is invertible iff the identity operator is compact iff the space is finite-dimensional

Comment: May be you can try to estimate $||T^n||^{\frac{1}{n}}$. If this tends to $0$. Then $\sigma(T)={0}$ by spectrum radical formula.